# Как передать управление конструктору базового класса при вызове конструктора класса-наследника

Tags: c#

Как при вызове конструктора класса-наследника передать управление конструктору базового класса?
Как при вызове одного конструктора класса передать управление другому конструктору класса?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конструктор базового класса:

```
// с вызовом конструктора по умолчанию из класса-предка
public MyClass() : base() 
{
    // ....
}

// с вызовом параметризованного конструктора из класса-предка
public MyClass(int first) : base(first) 
{
    // ....
}
```

Конструктор того же класса:

```
// использование конструктора по умолчанию того же класса
public MyClass(string first) : this() 
{
    // ....
}

public MyClass(int first, int second) : this(first) 
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: я бы добавил еще пример с вызовом параметризованного конструктора на всякий случай

Comment: А что к какому вопросу относится? я просто начинающий)

Comment: При создании класса, конструкторы для каждого класса в иерархии наследования будут вызваны по очереди, в порядке от самого базового -> к самому последнему в иерархии. При этом `: base() ` указывать не обязательно, т.к. вызов конструктора без параметров присходит по-умолчанию.